# MySQL only update if source = 2

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which I execute in a php forEach-loop:

```sql
INSERT INTO routes (id, train, operator, source) VALUES ('$idDate', '$id', '$operator', '1')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='$idDate', train='$id', source='1'
```

This query works and adds the data to the db, with 'source' telling me where it came from. It also updates the rows if 'id' already exists.

But I want it to only UPDATE if 'source' = '2'

Below is how I want it to work. ('id' is unique)

Source 1:

If row with 'id' don't exist, INSERT

If row with 'id' exist, UPDATE if 'source' = '2'

Source: 2

If row with 'id' don't exist, INSERT

If row with 'id' exist, UPDATE if 'source' = '2'

Is this possible? And in one query?
I have tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO routes (id, train, operator, source) VALUES ('$idDate', '$id', '$operator', '1')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id='$idDate', train='$id', source='1' WHERE source='2'
```